# Strategy with dependency

Tags: java, design-patterns, strategy-pattern

So a have a class called Dictionary. And one of its' method is

```
public boolean isRight(String word);
```

which searches if the word is in the collection of words (that's encapsulated).

```
private Set<String> rightWords;
```

So, I want to benchmark different types of searches that's why inside of this method I try to apply Strategy pattern.

```
public boolean isRight(String word){
        Strategy st = new FastStrategy(word);

        st.search();
        // else...
}
```

So, since I should look through the `rightWords` variable should I pass it through the constructor of strategy? But since the raw collection of words is private strategy won't have an access to it.

What should I do?

Also if I pass in a dependency to a strategy does it remain a strategy pattern?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since those strategies that you want to define are various ways to look up a needle in a haystack, you don't need to keep any state in them.

If you make them stateless, you can provide both the `word` and the `rightWords` with every invocation, as method arguments.

As for a way to define them, I would vote for an enum (implementing `java.util.function.BiPredicate` or some interface of your own if you're not using Java 8):

```
enum LookupStrategy implements BiPredicate<String, Set<String>> {
    FAST_LOOKUP {
        @Override public boolean test(String word, Set<String> rightWords) {
            return rightWords.contains(word);
        }
    },
    SLOW_LOOKUP {
        @Override public boolean test(String word, Set<String> rightWords) { ... }
    }
}
```

Then you can make your `Dictionary` class accept a strategy at construction time (using the interface type, not the actual enum defined above):

```
class Dictionary {
    private final Set<String> rightWords;
    private final BiPredicate<String, Set<String>> lookupStrategy;

    Dictionary(Set<String> rightWords, BiPredicate<String, Set<String>> lookupStrategy) {
        // initialize private fields
    }

    boolean isRight(String word) {
        return lookupStrategy.test(word, rightWords);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pass your Strategy as input on your `isRight()` method and it's still a Strategy pattern. `Collections.sort()` is one of the best examples of Strategy pattern that takes as input a `Comparator`.

But, you shouldn't initialize your Strategy object with an input `Strategy st = new FastStrategy(word);`, on the other hand, pass the `String word` as input to your `search()` method. For instance:

```
public boolean isRight(String word, Strategy st){
    ..
    st.search(word);
    // else...
}
```